# How to single And Double Click used in imagebutton for Android

Tags: android, button, imagebutton, double-click

i want to button setOnClicklister method in used single Click and Double Click .How to possible in android . I want to call to single click one action called and double click then webservice called. i want to single Click then dialog is open . My code in below.

Thanks!!!!

```
home_big_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    showCustomDialog(list.get(position).image);

                }

            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a small logic to accomplish your task:

On 1st click take the current system time and save it in a global or static variable. On second click, take the time again and see the difference with the provious time (Fix your time diffenece). based on this difference, try to figure out if its a single click or double click.

This link has the logic:

[Differentiate Single click and double click of a imageView in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262744/differentiate-single-click-and-double-click-of-a-imageview-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

For that create the static variable outside of the function and increment it inside the onclick function and initialize again to zero if double click is pressed

```
static int count=0;

home_big_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    count++;
                      if(count==1){
                    showCustomDialog(list.get(position).image);
                      }
                //double click
                 if(count==2){
                      //double function() 
                      count==0;
                      }
                          }
                         });
```

Comment: I used This Code count==0; but get error Syntax error on token "==", invalid AssignmentOperator;

Comment: i think you need to use = to assign and == for check like inside the if statement

Answer (score 0):

**You just use this function in your Activity...**

```
ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
```

**This code is Mentioned in your Activity On create...**

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);


                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:                   

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:                   
            }
    }
}
```

**Outside of On create ....**

```
  public class singleTablistener implements OnDoubleTapListener,OnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {        

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {          
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {          
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {                    
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
            float distanceX, float distanceY) {         
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {    
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {           
        return false;
    }


}
```

All the best...