# Apply double tap on textview is not working

Tags: android, textview, double

I want to trigger certain events on double tap of TextView.

```
final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context,new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.e("", "Open new activty here");
        return true;
    }
});
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextID);
tv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
```

This returns the ontapevent

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41586072/single-click-and-double-click-in-edittext-in-android-using-the-click-listener-s/41586210#41586210

Answer (score 3):

You may need to create new Class implements Onclick. Normal click will be delay as 400 ms until the second click is detected by using Timer. If no second click after 400 ms is not exist, it will consider One Tap

```
public abstract class DoubleClickListener implements OnClickListener {

    private Timer timer = null;  //at class level;
    private int DELAY   = 400;

    private static final long DOUBLE_CLICK_TIME_DELTA = 300;//milliseconds

    long lastClickTime = 0;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        long clickTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (clickTime - lastClickTime < DOUBLE_CLICK_TIME_DELTA){
            processDoubleClickEvent(v);
        } else {
            processSingleClickEvent(v);
        }
        lastClickTime = clickTime;
    }



    public void processSingleClickEvent(final View v){

       final Handler handler=new Handler();
       final Runnable mRunnable=new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                onSingleClick(v); //Do what ever u want on single click
            }
       };

       TimerTask timertask=new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                    handler.post(mRunnable);
            }
       };
       timer=new Timer();
       timer.schedule(timertask,DELAY);
    }


    public void processDoubleClickEvent(View v){
        if(timer!=null)
        {
             timer.cancel(); //Cancels Running Tasks or Waiting Tasks.
             timer.purge();  //Frees Memory by erasing cancelled Tasks.
        }

        onDoubleClick(v);//Do what ever u want on Double Click
    }

    public abstract void onSingleClick(View v);

    public abstract void onDoubleClick(View v);
}
```

How to use

```
view.setOnClickListener(new DoubleClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSingleClick(View v) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onDoubleClick(View v) {
                 // Your code here
            }
        });
```

Comment: Nice solution, works. Maybe a bit heavy - but suffices. Grrrreat!

Answer (score 1):

one of the lazy implementation

```
private static final long DOUBLE_CLICK_TIME_DELTA = 300;//milliseconds

long lastClickTime = 0;

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextID);
tv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        long clickTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (clickTime - lastClickTime < DOUBLE_CLICK_TIME_DELTA){
        lastClickTime = 0;
        //double click
    } else {
        //single click
    }
    lastClickTime = clickTime;
    }
});
```

but dont  be lazy if using double click again and again. go the better way..
Create a abstract class n go on..

```
public abstract class DoubleClickListener implements OnClickListener {

private static final long DOUBLE_CLICK_TIME_DELTA = 300;//milliseconds

long lastClickTime = 0;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    long clickTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (clickTime - lastClickTime < DOUBLE_CLICK_TIME_DELTA){
        onDoubleClick(v);
        lastClickTime = 0;
    } else {
        onSingleClick(v);
    }
    lastClickTime = clickTime;
}

    public abstract void onSingleClick(View v);
    public abstract void onDoubleClick(View v);
}
```

use it anywhere

```
view.setOnClickListener(new DoubleClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSingleClick(View v) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDoubleClick(View v) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work. What happens on a double click? [1] single click comes in ... there was no previous ... so the method is called. [2] Then a second click comes in ... but all has cleared. See below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement it all i think , Use this **Code:**

```
final GestureDetector gd = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
   //here is the method for double tap
    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {

        //your action here for double tap e.g.
        //Log.d("OnDoubleTapListener", "onDoubleTap");

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        super.onLongPress(e);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }


});

//here yourView is the View on which you want to set the double tap action

yourView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        return gd.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
```

Having said that it's more common in android to use longclick instead.